# How to obtain directories and subdirectories and group them by parent and children

Tags: java, file

I want to obtain all the directories and subdirectories from folder and grouping them based on parent and children.
I obtained all directories and subdirectories with the following codes :

```
String rootFolder = "/Users/user/Desktop/testFolder";

try (Stream<Path> paths = Files.walk(Paths.get(rootFolder))) {          
            List<String> pathStr = paths.filter(Files::isDirectory)
                    .map(path -> path.toString())
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());    

} catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

}
```

The results was like this :

```
/Users/user/Desktop/testFolder
/Users/user/Desktop/testFolder/folder1
/Users/user/Desktop/testFolder/folder1/folder1
/Users/user/Desktop/testFolder/folder2
/Users/user/Desktop/testFolder/folder2/folder1
/Users/user/Desktop/testFolder/folder3/folder1/folder1
```

For the next step I would like organise them into something like :

```
{
   path : "/Users/user/Desktop/testFolder",
   children : 
   [
      {
         path : "/Users/user/Desktop/testFolder/folder1",
         children : 
         [
            {
               path : "/Users/user/Desktop/testFolder/folder1/folder1",
               children : []
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         path : "/Users/user/Desktop/testFolder/folder2",
         children : 
         [
            {
               path : "/Users/user/Desktop/testFolder/folder2/folder1",
               children : []
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         path : "/Users/user/Desktop/testFolder/folder3",
         children : 
         [
            {
               path : "/Users/user/Desktop/testFolder/folder3/folder1",
               children : 
               [
                  {
                     path : "/Users/user/Desktop/testFolder/folder3/folder1/folder1",
                     children : []
                  }
               ]
            }
         ]
      }   
   ]
}
```

I have the following class ready :

```
public class PathTree {
    private String path;
    private List<PathTree> children;
}
```

I aware that using loop and check all those path prefix one by one should eventually achieve the result I want, but I would like to know if there is any alternative or solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can write a recursive method using

[walkFileTree​(Path start, Set options, int maxDepth, FileVisitor<? super Path> visitor)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#walkFileTree(java.nio.file.Path,java.util.Set,int,java.nio.file.FileVisitor))   Walks a file tree.

pseudo code

```
PathTree createTree(String root) {
    PathTree root = new PathTree(root)
    Files.walkFileTree(root, options, labda_add_children_to_root_above)
    root.children.foreach(c -> createTree(c.path))
    return root;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I obtained the result I wanted using recursive, but I used File.listFiles() instead of walkFileTree().